# updating text from a label.text to the server and saving it in a text file

Tags: php, objective-c, xcode, http-method

i am trying to upload label.text on a server within a text file on the server here is my code. it isnt showing any error but file created on server but no text in it. please help.

```
NSString *post =[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"VIN: %@",vincode.text];
        NSData *postData = [post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding
                              allowLossyConversion:NO];
        NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [postData
                                                                  length]];
        NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init]
                                        autorelease];
        [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"Server Detail Here/upload_vin.php"]]; 
        [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
        [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
        [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
       forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
        [request setHTTPBody:postData];
        NSData *urlData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request
                                                returningResponse:nil error:nil];
        NSLog(@"Succeeded! Received %d bytes of data",[urlData length]);
        NSLog(@"VIN is %@",vincode.text);
        NSString *outputdata = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:urlData
                                                     encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
        NSLog(@"Outputdata is %@",outputdata);
        NSURLResponse *response;
        NSError *error;
        [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error];
        if(error==nil)
            NSLog(@"Error is nil");
        else
            NSLog(@"Error is not nil");
        NSLog(@"success!");
PHP file::::::::::::::
    <?php
    $file = "VinCodes.txt";
    #$submitted_vincode = $_GET['VIN'] . " \n";
    $submitted_vincode = @$_POST['VIN'] . " \n";
    if(!empty($submitted_vincode)){
    $Handle = fopen($file, 'a');
        fwrite($Handle, $submitted_vincode); 
        print "Vin Code stored in file."; 
        fclose($Handle);
    }else{
        print "Vin code is missing. Try again";
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: $filecontents = file_get_contents("VinCodes.txt");
print $filecontents; could you please add this code and print your file

Answer (score 0):

Way to much code, here is what I do, (note I upload async):

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: @"http://..."];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setHTTPBody:data];
[request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request ...
```

BTW, are you sure you want `NSASCIIStringEncoding` and not `NSUTF8StringEncoding`?

When in doubt I use [Charles](http://www.charlesproxy.com) Web Proxy (free for 30 days) to see exactly what is sent and the response.

Comment: thank zaph for helping me out but kindly would u tell me what should be my exact code actually i am new with objective c so it would be very helpful if u tell main the WHOLE code part. can i do it with sendAsync? if yes then please can u provide complete code for this?

Comment: [request setHTTPBody:data];
didn't got this line??? please explain what is data here??(according to my code)